# The Software and Update section in settings is not working

Tags: 17.04, katoolin

I am new to Ubuntu. I installed 17.04 Zesty. Then I installed Kali repositories with a tool called Katoolin. But I think the installation was not successful. I ran

```
apt update
apt install -f
```

and also

```
apt upgrade
apt dist-upgrade
```

Now my current problem is I cannot open the Software and Update section in settings. I was hoping to remove the Kali repo source links from there and run `apt update` and `upgrade`, but I couldn't open up the settings.

Comment: How did you add it in the first place, remember that name(PPA)?

Comment: https://github.com/LionSec/katoolin does the rest

Answer (score 0):

A): You were warned not to update with the repos: ***Before updating your system , please remove all Kali-linux repositories to avoid any kind of problem .***

B): You remove the **repos** using the **katoolin** tool not using **Software and Update section in settings**

Now to remove do the following:

1. Run the `sudo katoolin` command
2. Select option `(1)` to `Add Kali repositories & Update`
3. Select option `(3)` to `remove all kali repositories`
4. Check and make sure the repos are gone after the command at `step 3`. Grep for it with:

   ```
   sudo grep -i -R "kali" /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
5. If `step 4` returns repos then use a text editor [I recommend nano for those not familiar with `vim`], to add `#` before each line or remove them completely. **PLEASE LOOK BEFORE ADDING**

   - Using `nano`:

     - `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`
     - To save: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>
     - To close: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>
6. Now update your system with:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```

**WARNING**:

Did you watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8VxCWVoZEEE